# Why called Akala Bodhana

Tags: puranas, tantra, durga, chandipath

In chapter 10, sloka 12 of Sri Sri Chandi, devi says :

> शरत्काले महापूजा क्रियते या च वार्षिकी
>
> meaning that in the sarat (autumn) seaon, my great annual puja is done. So in the very Chandi, Sri Sri Durga recognizes the saratkaalin durga puja.

Then why is it told that Rama worshipped Her first in an inappropriate time (Akala)? Chandi is from Swarochisha mannantwara by the way.

Comment: That means  ur question is "While it is the proper time to worship Durga why Rama's worship is called Akala Bodhana?

Comment: @Rickross yes. And if Rama already worshipped Devi in this form, why we genereally believe that it started with surath and samdhi?