Did Lord Ram pluck his eyes and offer to Durga devi?
Is the above incident mentioned in Original Ramayana?

Related questions (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26133), (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32106)

While offering 1008 lotuses during his puja to Goddess Durga one lotus was falling short .. since Rama's eyes resembled lotus (Padmalochana) he meant to offer one of his eyes instead of the flower but eventually he was stopped by Goddess herself ..this incident was probably mentioned in some minor Puranas (possibly in the Kalika Purana)

This incident is not mentioned in the Baroda Critical Edition of Valmiki Ramayana.
In fact, in the Bhagavad Gita, Bhagawan Krishna disapproves of self-torture.

mūḍhagrāhēṇātmanō yatpīḍayā kriyatē tapaḥ.
parasyōtsādanārthaṅ vā tattāmasamudāhṛtam৷৷17.19৷৷

17.19 That austerity which is practised from deluded notions by means of self-torture or in order to injure another is said to be Tamasika
So Bhagavan Rama plucking his own eyes as a means of tapasya, is out of the question.

The anecdote of Śrī Rāmacāndra worshipping Bhagavatī Durgā by offering his eyes is based on the Bengali retelling of the epic by poet Kṛttivāsa Ojhā. Here is the synopsis

Rāvaṇa was a devout worshipper of both Bhagavāna Śiva & Bhagavatī Adyāșakti, which made him invincible to everybody. On a particular day, when Rāvaṇa was on a tight corner in the battlefield against Śrī Rāmacāndra, he invoked Bhagavati Adyāșakti for protection. Śrī Rāmacāndra then saw Rāvaṇa being seated on the lap of Bhāgavatī Kālī, realising that She Herself was protecting him like Her own son. At this vision, He was dejected. Seeing this, Prajāpati Brahmā came forward & advised Him to propitiate Bhagavatī by performing Durgā Pūjā, with Brahmā acting as the purohita for Śrī Rāmacāndra. And one of the (if not the) most important rites of Durgā Pūjā is to offer 108 blue lotuses (arranged by Hanumāna) alongside 108 pradīpas to Devī Cāmuṇḍa during the Sandhi Pūjā (conducted on the last daṇḍa of aṣṭamī & first daṇḍa of navamī) for sealing the victory over Rāvaṇa. Bhagavatī Adyāșakti in order to test the firmness of Śrī Rāmacāndra's resolution, hid one lotus just when the rites of Sandhi Pūjā had started. When this was discovered, everybody was dejected. But Śrī Rāmacāndra, remembering that the ṛṣis have always compared his eyes with that of lotuses (N.B - Among many names of Bhagavāna Viṣṇu are Puṇḍarikākṣa meaning 'He whose eyes are like white lotuses' & Rājivalocana meaning 'He whose eyes are like red lotuses') & surely the ṛṣis will never lie for the sake of flattery. So He decided to offer one of his eyes as a substitute for the missing lotus. However, when He was going to uproot his eye for this purpose, Bhagavatī Durgā manifested before Him, revealed Her intentions & blessed Him with victory over Rāvaṇa. Meanwhile, Rāvaṇa who was conducting his separate worship with Bṛhaspati as the purohita was thwarted by Hanumāna, who disrupted Caṇḍīpāṭha & tricked Mandodarī to hand him the arrow designated to kill Rāvaṇa. And thus on the day of Vijayādaśamī, Śrī Rāmacāndra successfully killed Rāvaṇa on the battlefield with the blessings of Bhagavatī Durgā.

Each vernacular retelling of the original Sanskrit Rāmāyaṇa has its own unique legends inserted into it. For example - the original Rāmāyaṇa of Vālmīki has Śrī Rāmacandra becoming the host of Sābarī, while the Adhyātmya Rāmāyaṇa mentions Him accepting fruits & having a philosophical discourse on bhakti with her, and the Tulasīdāsa Rāmacaritamānasa contains the popular narrative of Śabarī tasting the fruits herself before offering the partly-eaten. Similarly, the Oṛiya retelling of the Mahabharata by Śāralādāsa has Kṛṣṇa turn into a grotesque chimaera-like being called Navaguñjara, which is extensively reproduced in the local patacitra art.
Some people may not accept all of this type of narrative found in local/retelling versions of Ramayana and may prefer to insist on the original Sanskrit only. However, we can refer some other texts also e.g.  Kṛttivāsa's retelling of Śrī Rāmacāndra's worship of Bhagavatī Durgā is based on the Devībhāgavata Purāṇa (which describes Śrī Rāmacandra observing Śāradīyā Navarātrī for gaining victory over Rāvaṇa) & Bṛhaddharma Purāṇa (which describes Śrī Rāmacāndra's performance of the Durgā Pujā), with oblique reference  in the Kālikā Purāṇa. Agni Purāṇa also mentions about propitiating Camuṇḍā through the Saṃgrāmavijaya mantra for ensuring victory in battlefield. The Tāntrika text Mahākālasaṃhitā credits Rāvaṇa with the sadhanā of Bhagavatī Guhyakālī. Although the notion of Śrī Rāmacāndra plucking off His eye for worship is completely devised by Kṛttivāsa himself, this notion isn't ingenious to him, for an almost similar anecdote is recorded in Bṛhaddharma Purāṇa:1:10
The short summary of the narrative is

On hearing that Bhagavāna Viṣṇu loves Bhagavāna Śiva more than Her, Bhagavatī Lakṣmī takes the vow of daily propitiating Bhagavāna Śiva with a lakh of lotuses daily in order to gain Her husband's unbroken love. And she did so daily. Bhagavāna Śiva, in order to test Bhagavatī Lakṣmī's resolution, hid 2 lotuses on day while Bhagavatī Lakṣmī was busy worshipping Him. When Bhagavatī Lakṣmī found out, She thought that it would be impious to leave the rites of worship midway in oder to get up & arrange for alternatives. Then She remembered that while in conjugal embrace, Bhagavāna Viṣṇu compared her breasts with lotus buds & surely the words of Her husband can't be false. So She then decided to offer Her own breasts as substitute for the missing pair of lotuses. She plucked off one breast & placed it on the shivaliṅga & was going to pluck off the other one, when Bhagavāna Śiva appeared before Her, desisting Her from the act  & revealing His intentions. He restored Her lost breast, blessed Her with limitless conjugal love from Her husband & transformed the already offered breast into a bilva fruit (which is also known as śrīphala meaning 'Śrī's fruit', decreeing that as a symbol of Her exemplary devotion, He will be pleased by the offerings of bilva leaves over other flowers.

Elsewhere we also have the famous Tamil narrative of Kannappā Nayanar offering his eye to Bhagavāna Śiva, so offering of one's body parts to propitiate a deity is quite a common narrative.

The question was whether it was found in the original Ramayana. It is not mentioned in the Valmiki Ramayana. Regional retellings are useless because these are not written in Sanskrit. These texts are not part of Hindu sacred literature. Even Srila Prabhupada said that he wanted to translate Valmiki Ramayana because that is the original Ramayana.

Most pop-culture retellings of the Ramayana are heavily based on the Avadhi Ramacharitamanasa (like the narratives of Shabari offering her leftover scraps to Sri Rama & Hanumana tearing off his chest out of bhakti). So it isn't unjust in asking that if people are to fanboy over one vernacular retelling, they might as well do the same with other vernacular retellings too. Besides, Valmiki Ramayana doesn't holds absolute monopoly over narrating Sri Rama's lifestory. The vernacular retellings are to be used for teaching purposes only, but not for establishing doctrine & determining dogmas.

Yes, I find it unfortunate that Ramcharitmanas is more popular than Valmiki Ramayan. It is hard to digest. I agree that "The vernacular retellings are to be used for teaching purposes only, but not for establishing doctrine & determining dogmas."
